# Does a user lose privilege if his reputation decreases below requirement by giving a bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, bounty, privileges

Here is a hypothetical question - Suppose I cross 1000 reputation and become an established user. Then I give 200 reputation as bounty on some problem, so my reputation goes down below 1000. Will I lose my established user privileges?

**P.S.**: I am not reputation hungry or anything like that. I just think that viewing upvotes and downvotes is kinda cool and I don't want to lose it once I get it.

Comment: Your privileges are base on reputation you have now. Past glory does nothing for you.

Comment: So, you say I'll lose the privileges.

Comment: Yes, [lose the privileges you will](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13000/206169).

Comment: I got my "Trivial answer converted to comment". *Thank you so much StackExchange*. // The logic behind this feature is that "trivial answer" means the question is really a duplicate. But what if it's a duplicate of a question on another SE site?

Comment: I can flag an answer to ask the mods to convert it to a comment. But I can't flag a comment to ask the mods to convert it to an answer. Sorry, @5PM, I wanted to help.

Comment: @5PM Just quote the answer from that question, that will prevent the automatic conversion. The trigger is a very short post with an internal link, adding more text prevents it. This feature is a bit annoying on meta.

Comment: Shortly after I crossed the 1000 threshold an earlier post was deleted and I lost enough points to take me below 1000 again. And yes, the privileges went as well. StackExchange giveth and StackExchange taketh away.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Given the ample evidence collected in the comments, including a [debate on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13000/206169), it is resolved that a user whose reputation decreases for whatever reason, shall lose any privileges associated with the earlier level of reputation.

Offering a bounty is making a sacrifice for the science. Not just a sacrifice of a lamb or a limb. You sacrifice: your reputation. Your ability to see (deleted questions). Your ability to write (in other's posts). Your ability to speak (by commenting). Eventually, you sacrifice your ability to make further sacrifices (set bounties). This is where it ends. But the [history](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/history-of-math-stackexchange) will remember.

Comment: It turns out I spent [1000 rep](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/53153/5pm?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on bounties already. Almost all of those questions remain unanswered, however.

Comment: One silly side effect of this is that, at 500 reputation, you're better off downvoting an answer and retagging (500-1+2=501) than just retagging (500+0=500). I imagine there might be similar things  at other thresholds, but it's a very small percentage of your reputation so that it is not a big issue.

Comment: @MarkS. For best results: downvote, retag, and undo the downvote for the net gain of 2 points. (Then weep and wonder where you life went so wrong. :)

Comment: +1 for the humor.

Comment: A sacrifice... for ***MATH!***

Comment: @MarkS., what do you mean by "retagging"?

Comment: @Wildcard I just meant changing the tags on a question.